# Mongoose: Transform data before sending it off to the requester

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Usually, Mongoose returns the data as received from the DB. Can we transform the data by deleting or modifying the values of certain data before returning it to the requester?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! You can use a middleware in Express (node.js) and because Mongoose is using its own object type of the returned data you can convert them into JS object with `mongooseReturn.toObject()` function or if you have an array of objects then you can use the `.lean(true)` in the query

Rer. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean

Ref. https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

if you show me your code I can show you exactly how to transform it, in one of my examples I am doing as such:

Assuming the models/drug.js with all the schema data. Then...

routes/drug.js:

```
..
..
let _middleware = require('../functions/middleware');

/* GET drugs find by comparing name. */
router.get('/search/:keyword', function(req, res, next) {
    Drugs
        .find({"name": { $regex: new RegExp("^" + req.params.keyword.toLowerCase(), "i")}})
        .limit(3)
        .lean(true)                                         //Ref. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean
        .exec(function(err, drugs) {
            if (err)
                return res
                    .status(500)
                    .send(err);

            _middleware.cleanHtml(drugs, function(cleanDrug){ //no .toObject() because of multiple objects

            res
                .status(200)
                .json(cleanDrug);
            });
        });
});
```

then you have in the middleware.js file that was required above this code:

```
module.exports = {
    cleanHtml: function(drugs, callback) {
        console.log("executing: cleanHtml()");

        try {
            if (drugs instanceof Array) {                                           //in case of an Array of JSONs, add or remove elements below
                console.log("Array of MANY come in for processing.");

                for (let drug of drugs){
                    drug = html_cleanup(drug);
                }

                return callback(drugs);
            } else {                                                                //in case of single JSON object, manipulate the key-value pairs of a single instance
                drugs = html_cleanup(drugs);
                return callback(drugs);
            }
        } catch(err) {
            console.log("\n\n == EXCEPTION (@Function: "
                + arguments.callee.name + "() @File: "
                + _inbuild.get_current_file_name(__filename)
                + "): \n\n"
                + err
                + "\n\n == END-OF-EXCEPTION \n\n");

            drugs['exception'] = err.toString();  //add error to returning variable
            return callback(drugs);
        }
    },

  };
}
```